# Flatui checkbox is not working

Tags: javascript, checkbox

In index file I have code for `flatui checbox`. `Checkbox` won't appear when I execute index.html. My flow of execution is:  `execute index.html -> click a button` then I can see `flatui checkbox`. Here the code for checkbox is execute first in index.html before it appear in browser, so when I try to click on checkbox after it render in browser it doesn't work. I have attached a image of checkbox. It doesn't work when I click on it.[image: flatui checkbox]

How can I make it work? I got this checkbox style from [this website](http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/)

**Update:** I guess, I need to execute a function when I render checkbox in my javascript file, that function must be from `flatui-checkbox.js`. But I don't which function should I execute.

Comment: try looking at the source of their demo page.

Comment: In my case, If I render `checkbox` in first page itself then it is working. But I am rendering `checkbox` in second page in the sense after click a button.

Comment: is there some code you can post? generally this happens when you use `.click` instead of `.on('click'`

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind a function to the checkbox like this:

```
$(':checkbox').on('toggle',  function(ui)=> {
    //your handler here
});
```